# How can I define build events (pre or post) for lightswitch projects in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

There must be something obvious I am missing, but I cannot find a way to define pre and post build events for lightswitch projects. Normally, you go to the project properties screen and see a "build events" tab and access the pre and post build event command lines.

When I go into the properties for the root lightswitch node in my solution explorer, I do not see build events there, and the same is true if I go into the properties for Client, Common or Server.

Can someone clarify what is the issue here?

Thanks,

Jaspreet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Visual Studio 2012 does not support pre and post build events for Lightswitch projects, at least not directly from the project properties. I asked the same question on [Lightswitch forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/35cc34c7-d3d8-4499-86f6-7c601bef3c85/#1a3c16fe-24fa-4dc1-84ec-47a9c4dee57d) and as recommended by Yann, I have made a [User Voice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3512037-add-pre-and-post-build-events-to-lightswitch-proje). You can vote on it if you care about this feature.